# Calculate Cartesian coordinates based on the distance and the angle

Tags: coordinate-systems

I'm trying to calculate the $x$ and $z$ coordinate of a coordinate based on the angle and the distance of the origin $(0,0,0)$. Even though I use a 3-dimensional system I watch from top down which basically means I ignore the $y$-axis. **See the image reference below so you can see what I mean.**

Assuming I have the correct distance in **Meters** and the angle in **Degrees** I could calculate the cartesian coordinates relative to the center.

For this I use the following formulas:

**X coordinate:** *d* * cos(*a* * π / 180)

**Z coordinate:** *d* * sin(*a* * π / 180)

The '*d*' is the distance, the '*a*' is the angle.

The formula's above are the only ones that I found online in terms of calculating cartesian coordinates based on angle and distance, so I figured they are correct. As you can see in the image below the $z$-axis (or the $y$-Axis) is reversed. But even when I multiply the $z$ value with $-1$ I get wrong values.

**Example:** If I were to have a distance of **5** and a angle of **45 degrees**
I should basically have the (rounded) coordinate $(3,53, 0, -3,53)$. Again, if you take the referenced image it makes more sense. I just replaced the $y$ with the $z$ axis.

Are the formulas wrong or am I doing something wrong? If you need something clearer just ask me and I'll try to explain it :)

Thanks in advance.

[image: Grid visualization image link (imgur)]

Comment: Is the "distance" you speak of the distance to the origin in 3-space or 2-space?  If You start with the point $(x,y,z)$ at distance $5$ from the origin, and project it to the point $(x,0,z)$, the projection will not be at distance $5$ from the origin (unless $y$ was $0$ to begin with.)

Comment: according to your picture, $z=-\cos(a\pi/180)$, $x= \sin(a\pi/180)$

Comment: @Vasya Tested it on paper, you seem to be correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that your equations are not consistent with your coordinate system.

Your equations are consistent with this coordinates, which is much more commonly used in mathematics:

[image]

Unless otherwise specified, mathematical articles usually use this coordinate system when dealing with 2D problems.

There are two main characteristics:

1. The vertical axis increases upward, and the horizontal axis increases rightward.
2. The angles are consistent with the right-hand grip rule: angle increases in the anticlockwise direction.

For your coordinate system, you need to modify your equations, which are stated in one of the comments on your question.